# Use imagick within Magento2 Custom controller

Tags: magento2, module, image, controllers

I have a beginners question.. I've built a custom module. **I want to use Imagick for image manipulation from within the controller.**

Imagick is properly installed on my server and works like charm from a normal `.php` file.

In my Controller I have

```
namespace <vendor>\<moduleName>\Controller\Index;
```

When trying to use Imagick

```
$image = new Imagick($imageFname);
```

I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   '\\Controller\Index\Imagick' not found.

Obviously it looks for Imagick in the wrong place because of the namespace, but I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add a backslash before the classname**. In your case, it looks in the wrong location because of the namespace.

Try:

```
$image = new \Imagick($imageFname);
```

Example from Magento 2 core file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Image/Adapter/ImageMagick.php#L251